Why is calling an external function in pmap() slower than executing code directly?
The following minimal example illustrates it:
dfr <- data.frame(x=1:1e6, y=1:1e6)
f <- function(x,y) x+y

# faster
system.time(
  for (i in 1:50) purrr::pmap(dfr, \(x,y) x+y)
)

# slower
system.time(
  for (i in 1:50) purrr::pmap(dfr, \(x,y) f(x,y))
)

In my actual case, f does a lot more stuff and the difference is ~2s vs. ~35s. There is probably an obvious reason for this, can someone explain?

Edit: Based on the answers in the comments so far, here is a more elaborate example with list-columns. Here, the function func takes in the (list-)columns of the dfr (a,b,c,d,e) as well as two additional args alpha, beta.
The result is, from fast to slow:

map(dfr, \(a,b,c,d,e) *execute code directly*)
map(dfr, func, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
map(dfr, \(a,b,c,d,e) func(a,b,c,d,e,alpha=alpha,beta=beta).

As per comments, the slowness of 3. has an extra level of function calling. But what about the slowness of 2. vs. 1. ?
I'd expect that, given that in 2. the additional arguments alpha and beta are just evaluated once, it would take as much time as 1.
dfr <- letters[1:5] |>
  purrr::set_names() |> 
  purrr::map(\(x) purrr::map(1:1e5, \(x) x)) |>
  tibble::as_tibble()

alpha <- 1
beta  <- 2

times <- data.frame(trial=1:100, t1=NA, t2=NA, t3=NA)

func <- \(a,b,c,d,e,alpha,beta) sum(a,b,c,d,e) * alpha * beta

for (i in seq_len(nrow(times))) {
  times$t1[[i]] <- system.time(
    purrr::pmap(dfr, \(a,b,c,d,e) sum(a,b,c,d,e) * alpha * beta)
  )[[3]]
  times$t2[[i]] <- system.time(
    purrr::pmap(dfr, func, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)
  )[[3]]
  times$t3[[i]] <- system.time(
    purrr::pmap(dfr, \(a,b,c,d,e) func(a,b,c,d,e,alpha,beta))
  )[[3]]
  message(i)
}

tidyr::pivot_longer(times, cols=c(t1,t2,t3)) |>
dplyr::summarise(mean=mean(value), sd=sd(value), .by=name)

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   name   mean      sd
#   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 t1    0.166 0.0127 
# 2 t2    0.183 0.00871
# 3 t3    0.240 0.0150 


When you use an anonymous function ((x, y) x + y) directly in pmap(), R treats it as an inline operation. This avoids the overhead of a separate function call each time pmap() iterates, making the operation faster.
However, when you pass f(x, y) to pmap(), R must evaluate f separately for each iteration. This incurs additional overhead because each function call requires.

@DavydAntoniuk Yes but the overhead is minuscule, and would most likely not be measurable at all by system.time(). And, notably, it shouldn’t depend on the contents of the function — on the contrary: for complex functions, the overhead should be relatively less important. … However, maybe R JIT-compiles the inline contents of the pmap call but doesn’t do the same for the function.

Your second method uses an extra level of function calling that isn't required. It should just be pmap(dfr, f). This removes the time difference.

The biggest win is if you can use vectorized operations.  Compare to with(dfr, x + y) which is much faster.

@AllanCameron that seems to be correct. Now, if f takes an additional argument a, then pmap(dfr, f, a=1) is consistently slower than pmap(dfr, \(x,y) x+a*y. Is the reasoning the same here?

I should also note that, in my actual use case (where dfr has list-columns, f uses more columns and does a lot more stuff and takes in additional arguments) it barely makes a difference whether I use pmap(dfr, \(x,y) f(x,y,a=1) or pmap(dfr, f, a=1). Both are at about 35s (vs. 2s for the fast method).

@AllanCameron That seems to indicate that the slow bit here is creating a function. That’s highly disconcerting, since it should only happen once per pmap() invocation (so it should be completely negligible unless it’s insanely slow!), and given that R highly encourages users to create functions frequently (in particular, f(vec, g) and f(vec, \(x) g(x)) are absolutely not equivalent due to scoping, and using the first will fail in some situations with incredibly hard-to-debug issues).

@KonradRudolph that's now how I interpreted that result. If you call pmap(list(xvals, yvals), \(x, y) f(x, y)) then the lambda is invoked length(xvals) times. On each occasion, R has to set up a new environment for the lambda call, which takes a little time. Also, compared to passing f directly, the call stack is one element deeper, and the search path for looking up the symbols to be evaluated in the body of f is more convoluted. Could that account for the difference?

@AllanCameron (“now” = “not”?) Yes, I have no idea why I wrote that yesterday. Brain hiccup. It’s (pretty certainly) due to the factors you enumerated.
